# How to select multiple values in a bidirectional many to many relationship based on input array

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, database, union-all

**How to make the select statement below handle multiple inputs (a list) at once and still return a similar resulting list as to that of a single input**

It's been hours, and I'm stuck - I need help writing a mysql statement to retrieve a list of ids from a table where a "link" is found.

The idea behind this question is to feed the query an array of id values, and have it return all other id's that are linked, from both sides of the table, to each of the id's passed in from the array into a single comma delineated list.

**table structure "team_permissions"**

```
first_teamID  |  second_teamID
  113         |     112
  114         |     112
  118         |     117
  119         |     112
  119         |     113
  119         |     114
```

**Working "get permissions per single team" sql statement** -- need to feed a list into this

```
SELECT first_teamID AS team_permissions 
FROM team_permissions
WHERE second_teamID = ?

UNION ALL

SELECT second_teamID AS team_permissions 
FROM team_permissions
WHERE first_teamID = ?
```

**Expected Single Input -> Output Examples** - this works

- (? = 112) will yield the result: [113,
  114, 119]
- (? = 113) will yield the
  result: [112, 119]
- (? = 117) will
  yield the result: [118]
- (? = 119) will
  yield the result: [112, 113, 114]

**Expected Multiple Input -> Output Examples**

- (? = [112, 113] ) will yield the result: [112, 113,
  114, 119]
- (? = [113, 119] ) will yield the result: [112, 113, 114, 119]
- (? = [112, 114, 118] ) will yield the result: [112, 113, 114, 117, 119]

[team_permissions table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMCmE.jpg)

Comment: You are looking for pivot function that does not exist in mysql.
You can do it programmatically, by issuing several queries.
Look at some examples in here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns
and here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `WHERE IN`, e.g.:

```
SELECT first_teamID AS team_permissions 
FROM team_permissions
WHERE second_teamID IN (113, 119)
UNION ALL
SELECT second_teamID AS team_permissions 
FROM team_permissions
WHERE first_teamID IN (113, 119)
```

Comment: I knew there was a simple answer to this problem. Thanks Tim! The WHERE IN clause did the trick.